# Meteor Not Excluding Node Modules in the Private Folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, gruntjs, isobuild

I'm adding my own grunt build setup to my meteor project and assumed from the docs that if I put it into the private folder, it would be left alone by iso-build.  Alas this is not the case, and all manner of hell breaks loose.

I'd like to know why?

A simple solution is to put my assets folder outside the meteor folder, which I'm fine with.

**NB :** I'm not looking to debate the validity using grunt in this situation, I'm interesting in understanding how iso-build treats folders, and how, if possible, to implement some control over what it includes or ignores etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically meteor doesn't ignore npm modules in the private directory, i've gone with the strategy of moving my grunt setup and assets outside of the meteor directory and have my assets moved by grunt into the public directory.